# How to readd a dash after exploding input in PHP

Tags: php

I have input coming into my website from a database. The format is XXX-XXX or XXXX-XXXX. It is not number formated. I can't simply do a number_format. I have worked on it and I just need to readd a dash.

```
$input = "1000-1199";
$explodedInput = explode("-",$input);
foreach ($explodedInput as $item) {
    echo number_format("$item");
}
```

Output = 1,0001,199
I want = 1,000-1,199

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
$input = "1000-1199";
$explodedInput = explode("-",$input);
$array = array();
foreach ($explodedInput as $item) {
    $array[] = number_format("$item");
}

echo implode("-", $array);
```

Answer (score 5):

One way:

```
echo implode('-', array_map('number_format', $explodedInput));
```

Gets rid of the `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Implode it back rather than echoing it:

```
$input = "1000-1199";
$explodedInput = explode("-",$input);
foreach ($explodedInput as $k => $item) {
    $explodedInput[$k] = number_format("$item");
}

echo implode('-', $explodedInput);
```